# Hide list element if list is empty?

Tags: wordpress

I am a beginner of Wordpress. I am trying to hide listing element if the value is empty in WordPress for the front view.

```
<ul>
        <li>
          <label>Category :</label>
          <span><?php echo get_field('category') ?></span>
        </li>

        <li>
          <label>Status :</label>
          <span><?php echo get_field('status') ?></span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check first that it is empty or nott like below

if(get_field('status')){ // your code }

Comment: you can mark as resolved if this is useful